# Where is the documentation for temporal tables in Flink 1.13?

Tags: apache-flink

Flink 1.11 has documentation about `temporal tables` at
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html

But I didn't find `temporal_tables` explanation for the Flink 1.13, could you please point it to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, with 1.13, the documentation has much better search functionality.

The content you're looking for was moved to https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/concepts/legacy/.

See also https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#temporal-joins.